# Libtool not creating version info symlinks during make install

Tags: cross-compiling, automake, libtool

I am seeking for help with awkward issue with libtool while building this library: http://github.com/mspanc/vspec

When i build it on my ubuntu 14.04 box, it works fine, add during make install it creates appropriate .so.VERSION_INFO symlinks.

However, when I try to cross compile it using Cerbero build system from GStreamer project (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/), which basically bootstraps toolchains for cross-compilation, during make install it creates only .so files (no .so.VERSION_INFO symlinks), but only for this library, it makes this succesfully for other libs within the same build environment.

Apparently, there must be some difference, but I diff automakes of vspec and other project that installs fine for quite some time already and still can't figure out what's the root cause of the problem.

I have found out that `libtool` script in the broken library generated while running `./configure --prefix /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7 --libdir /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib  --disable-maintainer-mode  --disable-silent-rules  --disable-introspection  --host=arm-linux-androideabi` has `version_type=none` while one that builds has this variable properly set to `linux`. That difference later causes libtool to not add symlinks.

Can anyone here give me any hint where should I seek for what causes invalid host recognition while generating `libtool`?

Below log from Cerbero's make install:

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libvspec-1.0.la '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.so /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/libvspec-1.0.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.lai /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/libvspec-1.0.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.a /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
libtool: install: arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib /root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
 /bin/mkdir -p '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/share/vala/vapi'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec-1.0.vapi libvspec-1.0.deps '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/share/vala/vapi'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/include/libvspec-1.0'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec.h '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/include/libvspec-1.0'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec-1.0.pc '/root/cerbero/dist/android_armv7/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/cerbero/sources/android_armv7/libvspec-1.0-1.0.0'
Running command 'make install'
```

And the same command on my ubuntu 14.04 box:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sudo make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libvspec-1.0.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0 libvspec-1.0.so.1 || { rm -f libvspec-1.0.so.1 && ln -s libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0 libvspec-1.0.so.1; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0 libvspec-1.0.so || { rm -f libvspec-1.0.so && ln -s libvspec-1.0.so.1.0.0 libvspec-1.0.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.lai /usr/local/lib/libvspec-1.0.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libvspec-1.0.a /usr/local/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libvspec-1.0.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/vala/vapi'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec-1.0.vapi libvspec-1.0.deps '/usr/local/share/vala/vapi'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/libvspec-1.0'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec.h '/usr/local/include/libvspec-1.0'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libvspec-1.0.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/marcin/aktivitis/radiokit/vspec'
```

Thanks,

Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, this is expected libtool output for this platform. See comments on [this libtool patch](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool-patches/2013-06/msg00002.html).  Versioned libraries [will not be added](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/_UhNpRJlA1k) to Android.